# Conditional probability between two random variables

Tags: statistics, random-variables, conditional-probability

A conditional probability $P(X |Y)$ where $X$ and $Y$ are two random variables can be represented in a graphical way as:

[image]

Now, my question is: does $P(X=x|Y)$ make sense?

If the answer is affirmative, this means that $P(X=x|Y)$ is only a function of $Y$, then $P(X=x|Y) = f(Y)$?

Please, clarify with a clear example.

Comment: Could you please give (or link to) a mathematical definition of $P(X\mid Y)$ where $X$ and $Y$ are two random variables. If $P$ is the probability measure, I only know definitions of $P(X\mid Y)$ where $X$ is an event, and I don't know any way to make sense of your graphical figure. If $P$ is not a probability measurement over events, then your definition will tell us what $P$ is.

Comment: @DavidK I don't have references in fact I'm not sure, but I thought about that representation considering this example: consider a random variable X as the sum of the outcomes of rolling two dice and another random variable Y as the outcome of the first dice. I can represent P(X | Y) as a function of both X and Y.
What do you think about this point of view? My representation of P(X|Y) makes sense now? Or it's wrong anyway?

Answer (score 1):

"$P(X \mid Y)$ where $X$ and $Y$ are two random variables" makes no sense to me,
so I will not discuss it.

But $P(X = x\mid Y)$ where $X$ and $Y$ are two random variables is a well-known notation (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability#Conditioning_on_a_random_variable).
We have that $P(X = x\mid Y)$ is a random variable whose value depends on the random variable $Y.$
That is, when $Y$ takes on the value $y,$ then $P(X = x\mid Y)$ takes on the value
$P(X = x\mid Y = y).$